# Why would "\n" become "^@" when writing Python in a .vim file?

Tags: python, vim, vim-plugin

For example, here is my function:

```
function! Test()
python << EOF
import vim
str = "\n\n"
vim.command("let rs = append(line('$'), '%s')"%str)
EOF
endfunction
```

and when I `:call Test()` , what I see is "^@^@".
Why would this happen and how can I use the origin '\n' ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two things: Vim internally stores *null* bytes (i.e. `CTRL-@`) as `<NL>` == `CTRL-J` for implementation reasons (the text is stored as C strings, which are null-terminated).

Additionally, the `append()` function only inserts multiple lines when passed a *List* of text lines as its second argument. A single String will be inserted as *one line*, and (because of the translation), the newlines will appear as `CTRL-@`.

Therefore, you need to pass a List, either by building a Python List, or by using the `split()` Vim function to turn your single String into a List:

```
function! Test()
python << EOF
import vim
str = "\n"
vim.command("let rs = append(line('$'), split('%s', '\\n', 1))"%str)
EOF
endfunction
```